# How to pass a parameter from a Laravel controller to a model hasmany function

Tags: eloquent, left-join, parameter-passing, laravel-5.8, has-many

I have an app with categories and subcategories, and I need to translate all of them to multiple languages. I want to retrieve all of the categories with their subcategories, along with any translations that exist, using a leftJoin.

It's been impossible to find documentation on how to pass a parameter from the controller to the model's function. I've seen lots of (similar) suggestions on ways to get around it, but nothing that explains how to pass the parameter.

This is in the model:

```
    public function subcats(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\SongCategory','parent_id','id')->orderby('sort_order','ASC');
    }

    public function subcatwithtranslations($lang="es"){
        return $this->hasMany('App\SongCategory','parent_id','id')->where('song_categories.language','en')
             ->leftJoin('song_category_translations',function ($join) use ($lang){
                        $join->on('song_categories.id', '=', 'song_category_translations.song_category_id') ;
                        $join->where('song_category_translations.language','=',$lang) ;
                    })
            ->select('song_categories.*', 'song_category_translations.id AS trans_id', 'song_category_translations.category_name AS translation')
            ->orderby('sort_order','ASC');
    }
```

I can get all of the parent categories, with any translations that exist, along with all the subcategories (but missing any subcategory translations) this way:

```
            $querys = SongCategory::with('subcats')
                ->where('parent_id',0)
                ->where('song_categories.language','en')
                 ->leftJoin('song_category_translations',function ($join) use ($lang){
                            $join->on('song_categories.id', '=', 'song_category_translations.song_category_id') ;
                            $join->where('song_category_translations.language','=',$lang) ;
                        })
                ->select('song_categories.*', 'song_category_translations.id AS trans_id', 'song_category_translations.category_name AS translation')
                ->OrderBy($orderby,$dir);
```

When this is in the controller:

```
            $querys = SongCategory::with(['field', 'song_categories.subcatwithtranslations($lang)'])
                ->where('parent_id',0)
                ->where('song_categories.language','en')
                 ->leftJoin('song_category_translations',function ($join) use ($lang){
                            $join->on('song_categories.id', '=', 'song_category_translations.song_category_id') ;
                            $join->where('song_category_translations.language','=',$lang) ;
                        })
                ->select('song_categories.*', 'song_category_translations.id AS trans_id', 'song_category_translations.category_name AS translation')
                ->OrderBy($orderby,$dir);
```

I get "Call to undefined relationship [field] on model [App\SongCategory]. RelationNotFoundException.php

If I do it this way as some have suggested as an alternative to passing the parameter to the model:

```
            $querys = SongCategory::with(array('subcatwithtranslations'=>function($query) use ($lang){
                    $query->where('song_category_translations.language',$lang); // This pre-filters the subcats and breaks the left join
                }))
                ->where('parent_id',0)
                ->where('song_categories.language','en')
                 ->leftJoin('song_category_translations',function ($join) use ($lang){
                            $join->on('song_categories.id', '=', 'song_category_translations.song_category_id') ;
                            $join->where('song_category_translations.language','=',$lang) ;
                        })
                ->select('song_categories.*', 'song_category_translations.id AS trans_id', 'song_category_translations.category_name AS translation')
                ->OrderBy($orderby,$dir);
```

Then the leftJoin for the subcategories to their translations is negated before we even start, and I only get the subcategories that are already translated.

If I try to get the subcategories with translations, without even passing the language, but hard-coding it in the model via the default, like this:

```
           $querys = SongCategory::with('subcattranslations')
                ->where('parent_id',0)
                ->where('song_categories.language','en')
                 ->leftJoin('song_category_translations',function ($join) use ($lang){
                            $join->on('song_categories.id', '=', 'song_category_translations.song_category_id') ;
                            $join->where('song_category_translations.language','=',$lang) ;
                        })
                ->select('song_categories.*', 'song_category_translations.id AS trans_id', 'song_category_translations.category_name AS translation')
                ->OrderBy($orderby,$dir);
```

I get an error, Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist

How do I pass the parameter to the model function so that I can do a left join?